# What is wrong with my to_s method for an inherited Circle class?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I am writing a program with 4 classes (Point, Shape, Rectangle, Circle). Rectangle and Circle inherit from Shape, which contains the information (a field) for the center of the shape. I am trying to write a to_s method for the Circle class, which is supposed to print out like the following:

> Circle: [(1, 2), 3]

(1,2) being the center and 3 being the radius. This is what I have for the to_s method:

```
def to_s
  "Circle: [(" + super.x.to_s + ", " + super.y.to_s + "), " + 
    radius.to_s + "]"
end
```

I am getting an error "No such method 'x' error", and I understand that it is because Shape does not have an 'x' method (it is in Point). I tried some long method chaining like super.center.y.to_s, but that has problems of its own. What is the correct way to go about doing this. i.e., good programming style, object oriented way, and ruby way?

Comment: I'm confused with your class definitions. Can you include them in the question?

Comment: You should use string interpolation instead of addition, it's cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `super` sends the parent class's `to_s` method, the result (a string) of which you're then sending `x`, `y`, etc, which are methods that don't exist for strings.

Try this:

```
def to_s
  "Circle: [(#{x},#{y}) #{radius}]"
end
```

Ruby has implicit string interpolation, meaning that in a double-quoted string, anything inside `#{...}` will automatically be rendered as a string.

What do expect to get from `x` if there is no `x` defined in `Shape` or `Circle`? Does `Shape` inherit from `Point`?

**Edit:**

To access the instance variable `@center`, which holds the `x` and `y` values, you have a few options. This is the most basic:

```
class Shape
  attr_accessor :center

  def initialize(point)
    @center = point
  end
end

class Circle

  def initialize(point, radius)
    super(point) # this runs Shape's initialize method
    @radius = radius
  end

  def to_s
    "Circle: [(#{center.x},#{center.y}) #{radius}]"
  end
end
```

Another option is to use the built-in Forwardable module:

```
require 'forwardable'
class Shape
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@center, :x, :y
  #...
end
```

Then in your instances, you can call `x` and `y` directly, and they will automatically be forwarded to `@center`, in which case the "Circle: [(#{x},#{y}) #{radius}]" string will work.

Comment: I understand how to works however that does not solve the bigger problem of the fact that the super class doesn't have the 'x' method so it still throws that error.

Comment: The error is because calling `super` routes to the `to_s` method of the parent class. It wouldn't work even if `x` was defined on `Shape`, because chaining it onto `to_s` is like saying `"string".x`. Where do your x and y come from for the circle?

Comment: The point class. Shape (Circle's parent) has a field @center that is a point, that's why I was trying to method chain with .x.

Comment: The only reason you should be using `super` at all in this context is to refer to the previous implementation of the `to_s` method. As Zach says, call your `x` and `y` methods directly. The reason for sub-classes is they *inherit* the methods of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby super is only a method representing an over written method not the superclass itself.

example:

```
class A
    def to_s
        'A'
    end
end

p A.new.to_s #=> returns 'A'

class B < A
    def to_s
        super + 'with' + 'B'
    end
end

p B.new.to_s #=> returns 'A with B'
```

If you didn't get that, invoking `super` only calls `A.to_s` and not `A` itself so if `A` had a property `x` calling `super.x` would fail because `super` only represents the currently overridden method it's called in and not the entire superclass. Now, to access the superclass's properties you only have to call `@x.to_s` or `self.x.to_s` as the superclass's properties belong to the subclass.